# If statement containing char not executing

Tags: java, if-statement, char

I'm trying to create a program that tests for the number of "correct" answers in every ten places in an array. I find that the if loop with the condition `textarray[i * 10 + k] == answerarray[k]` does not execute even when the conditions are met (I have verified this).

The else if statement `textarray[i * 10 + k] == ' '` is working, so I do not see why the former doesn't. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
char[] textarray = new char[textfile.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < textfile.length(); i++) {
    textarray[i] = textfile.charAt(i);
}

double[] eachquestiona = new double[10];
double[] eachquestionb = new double[10];
double[] eachquestionc = new double[10];
double[] eachquestiond = new double[10];
double[] eachquestione = new double[10];

//stores how many questions each student got correct, incorrect or left blank
int[] studentcorrect = new int[textfile.length() / 10];
int[] studentincorrect = new int[textfile.length() / 10];
int[] studentblank = new int[textfile.length() / 10];

for (int i = 0; i < textfile.length() / 10; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        if (textarray[i * 10 + k] == 'A') {
            eachquestiona[i]++;
        }

        if (textarray[i * 10 + k] == 'B') {
            eachquestionb[i]++;
        }

        if (textarray[i * 10 + k] == 'C') {
            eachquestionc[i]++;
        }

        if (textarray[i * 10 + k] == 'D') {
            eachquestiond[i]++;
        }

        if (textarray[i * 10 + k] == 'E') {
            eachquestione[i]++;
        }

        if (textarray[i * 10 + k] == answerarray[k]) {
            studentcorrect[i]++;
        }
        else if (textarray[i * 10 + k] == ' ') {
            studentblank[i]++;
        }
        else {
            studentincorrect[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume the repeated `for (int i = 0; ...` is a typo?

Comment: How is `answerarray` declared?

Comment: BTW, `String` has a `toCharArray()` method that would make your first loop unnecessary.

Comment: Have you tried a simple debugging statement?  Maybe this will help: `System.out.println(textarray[i * 10 + k] + " " + answerarray[k]);`

Comment: Thanks guys I figured it out. Turns out it was a problem earlier in my code. I had 

    for (int i = 0; i < textfile.length(); i++)
      {
       answerarray[i] = answers.charAt(i);
      }
instead of 
    for (int i = 0; i < answers.length(); i++)
      {
       answerarray[i] = answers.charAt(i);
      }
and btw, The double for loop was intentional. The first one tracked the columns, the second one tracked the row.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a bit of a mess, so I'll take the first pass at your SO code reivew:

First you need to fix the issues Edd and Baldy pointed out.  We also need to know what is "textfile"?  Without the data type, I'm not sure if either "charAt", or "length" is evaluating as you'd expect.

Also, not sure that this causing your problem, but your indexing is screwed up. You should be using

> eachquestiona[k]++

not

> eachquestiona[i]++

I'd also change the "if" statements between A and "answerArray" to "else if" statements (it shouldn't be more than one), move the blank check to after them, then have your "answerarray" check last before the final else incorrect (without an "else if" before it).  It can't be both 'A' and 'B' and ' ', and your code should reflect that.  It is either correct or incorrect (theoretically ' ' could be the correct answer).

Edit:

There are actually a lot of changes I'd make to this code to make it clearer (which will probably make the errors jump out at you), here is my reworking of it:

```
String textFile=//Initialize it here and show us how you did
final int NUMQUESTIONS = 10; //This may become a variable later
final int NUMSTUDENTS = textFile.length() / NUMQUESTIONS; //Probably should check that this is correct
double[] eachquestiona = new double[NUMQUESTIONS];
double[] eachquestionb = new double[NUMQUESTIONS];
double[] eachquestionc = new double[NUMQUESTIONS];
double[] eachquestiond = new double[NUMQUESTIONS];
double[] eachquestione = new double[NUMQUESTIONS];

//stores how many questions each student got correct, incorrect or left blank
int[] studentcorrect = new int[NUMSTUDENTS];
int[] studentincorrect = new int[NUMSTUDENTS];
int[] studentblank = new int[NUMSTUDENTS];

for (int studentCount = 0; studentCount < NUMSTUDENTS; studentCount++) {
    for (int answerCount = 0; answerCount < NUMQUESTIONS; answerCount++) {
        char thisAnswer=Character.toUpperCase(charAt(studentCount * NUMQUESTIONS + answerCount));
        switch(thisAnswer) {
            case 'A': eachquestiona[answerCount]++; break;
            case 'B': eachquestionb[answerCount]++; break;
            case 'C': eachquestionc[answerCount]++; break;
            case 'D': eachquestiond[answerCount]++; break;
            case 'E': eachquestione[answerCount]++; break;
            case ' ': studentblank[studentCount]++; break;
        }

        if (thisAnswer == Character.toUpperCase(answerarray[answerCount])) {
            studentcorrect[studentCount]++;
        } else {
            studentincorrect[studentCount]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Forgive me if there are typo's - I haven't actually run this.